# How to do this PHP find-replace

Tags: php, string, replace

I think I need to use the `preg_replace` function but not sure exactly how to type in the patterns I want to find and replace. Basically, I want to replace this:

```
: u"x"x",
```

with this:

```
: u"x'x",
```

`x` means that any characters can go there. But I don't know how to write the `x` in PHP.

Thank you!

Edit: basically, I want to replace that middle double-quote with a single-quote. And I'll be searching through a big JSON file to do it. Probably should have said this at the start.

Comment: Please provide examples with actual values for `x`, otherwise there remains ambiguity of what you really mean. Like: is `x` just one character or can it be several in sequence? Is the first `x` (whatever it is) the *same* as the second `x`?

Comment: Also, can `x` be one (or several) of `'` or `"`?

Comment: I know so little to care at this point. Walk before I can run. Any character. Since any character = any character, yes, both "x" characters are equal.

Comment: @PatrickQ yeah, anything

Comment: Can `x` be "abc"? or only individual characters like "a" or "b" or "c"?

Comment: Is `: u"a"b",` a string that would match, or should it be `: u"a"a",`?

Comment: All of the above. "abc", "a", "b", "c" are all good. And yeah the `x` values can be different to each other.

Comment: @NickGiordano So, how would you define the logic that specifies _which_ double-quote should be replaced with a single-quote, if each `x` can _contain_ multiple double-quotes?

Comment: OK, so both `x` do *not* have to be equal. Requirements need a more precise language than colloquial speach. ;-)

Comment: What should happen if input is `: u"abc"def"ghi"jkl"many more characters here with many more double quotes`?

Comment: @trincot yeah I am not always very clear. I was saying x = anything so yes they're equal in that way. But they don't HAVE to be equal, and thus aren't necessarily equal. First x could be "shdhgh" and second could be "thotrhotrhrth".

Comment: @trincot that scenario wouldn't happen in the code I have. I know it's good  practice to watch out for any potential problems, but I need a quick fix.

Comment: @PatrickQ i wouldn't be watching out for that possibility. just need a quick fix.

Comment: @NickGiordano "that scenario wouldn't happen in the code I have"  So then the text couldn't be "anything", as you've stated multiple times.  If you can't provide specific rules, we can't provide code for it.

Comment: BTW, the answers below were given more than 20 minutes ago. Did you check only one?

Comment: @PatrickQ Is there a PHP character to represent any character? That's what I need. Ah I just got what the problem is now. If that first `x` contains a double-quote mark then it won't know where the middle quote mark is that needs replacing. Can you look at the edit I made to my main post? That's what I need help with.

Comment: @trincot no I looked at them all. 2 of the 3 are identical in code, and they don't work. And neither does the other one.

Comment: Please provide in your question an example that fails for all answers below. Provide the input and the expected output for it.

Comment: @trincot no, my bad, your code you posted worked. I thought it was the same as the code someone else posted. Need sleep, sorry.

Comment: OK. Now the task is to mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regular expression:

```
$result = preg_replace('#(: u".*?)"(.*?")#', "$1'$2", $string);
```

Comment: This worked! Sorry, for some reason I thought this post had identical code to the one above.